# Could not load resource "WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml" in archive "xxxx"

Tags: java

I was trying to execute ear in WebSphere server it gives the error as"

```
 The exception com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.
         AppDeploymentException: [Root exception is 
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ResourceLoadException: 
 IWAE0007E Could not load resource "WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml" 
 in archive "GLOBISWeb.war"] occurred. Check log for details
```

My ear already have this **ibm-web-bnd.xml**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

> The web application will gets installed on WebSphere Application
>   Server Versions 5.0 and 5.1, but fails on a WebSphere Application
>   Server Version 6.0 or later server. The application fails to install
>   because the `WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi` file contains `xmi` tags that
>   the underlying WCCM model no longer recognizes.
>
> To work around this problem, remove the `xmi:type=EJBLocalRef` tag
>   from the `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` file. Removing this tag does not affect the
>   application because the tag was previously used for matching the cross
>   document reference type. The application now works for the WebSphere
>   Application Server Version 5.1 and later releases.

For more details regarding the issue visit [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rtrb_installappprob.html) and review under the section **Cannot load resource WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi in archive file**

Comment: xmi:type=EJBLocalRef tag not contain in ibm-web-bnd.xmi it contain in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi.